# Align the middles of two views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I use a relative layout. I was wondering, if I want to place a text field to the right "of the middle" of another view (say imageview). How can I do it?  I always know how to place it to the right, but it seems that the middles of both views are not aligned

Thanks

Comment: can you attach some picture of your requirement, so that it will help us to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Put them both in a relative layout, and set the gravity for the relative layout to center.